# Undertow enable url rewriting

Tags: jboss, undertow

I'm new on Undertow and don't know how to enable url rewriting.

In tomcat I use [tuckey filter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)  to rewrite my url. However this does not seem to work in Undertow.

So is possible to enable url rewriting in undertow?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this does not seem to be very documented.

Try [Handlers.rewrite()](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/78e43480c30ee057b41fb7841aebce28c2041bbf/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/Handlers.java#L373) and look at this [test case](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/78e43480c30ee057b41fb7841aebce28c2041bbf/core/src/test/java/io/undertow/server/handlers/PredicatedHandlersTestCase.java) that uses a sort of route mapping DSL.